# Room database: NOT NULL constraint failed at deletion

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have the following entities, `Session` and `Label`:

```
@Entity(
    foreignKeys =
    @ForeignKey(
            entity = Label.class,
            parentColumns = {"id", "archived"},
            childColumns = {"labelId", "archived"},
            onUpdate = CASCADE,
            onDelete = SET_DEFAULT))
    public class Session {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;

    @Nullable
    public String label = null;

    public boolean archived = false;
}

@Entity(primaryKeys = {"id", "archived"})
public class Label {

    @NonNull
    public String id;

    public boolean archived = false;
}
```

When deleting a `Label` attached to a `Session` I'm getting a `NOT NULL constraint failed` for `Session.archived`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `childColumns` with same name `"archived"` with `parentColumns` is ok in this case? Did that cause the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the issue is with using a type of **boolean** as in `public boolean archived = false;`.

As **boolean** is a Java primary type then it has an implicit **@NonNull** (the table is created with the NOT NULL constraint)

With Room you cannot (I beleive) set default values that are generated in the SQLite table so when using `onDelete SET_DEFAULT` the default value will be **NULL** as no actual default value has been set.

- Note Room does now support default values using [defaultValue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo.html#defaultValue()) within the [@ColumnInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo.html) annotation.
- using `= false` does not affect the actual SQLite table i.e. the column definition, if using **Boolean**, will be `labelId INTEGER` not `labelId INTEGER DEFAULT 0`.

Assuming that NULL is acceptable, then you can use **Boolean** (the Object) instead of boolean (the primary type). Objects can be null.

i.e. in **Session** use

```
public Boolean archived = false;
```

### Visual explantion :-

The following is the code, generated by Room, for the Session Entity but with an additional column added using :-

```
.........
public boolean archived = false;
public Boolean other_archived = false; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
........
```

Code Generated by Room :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Session` (
    `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    `label` TEXT, 

    `archived` INTEGER NOT NULL, /*<<<<<<<<<< boolean so NOT NULL */ 
    `other_archived` INTEGER, /*<<<<<<<<<< Boolean so no NOT NULL */
    FOREIGN KEY(`label`, `archived`) REFERENCES `Label`(`id`, `archived`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET DEFAULT)
```

---

### Extra

If you wanted the archived column in the Session table to be 0 (false), then you would have to modify the table. This would entail

1. Creating a replacement table that is the same except that the label column definition would be `label INTEGER DEFAULT 0` (i.e. DEFAULT 0 is added)
2. Copying the data from the Session table into the replacement table e.g. `INSERT INTO replacement_Session SELECT * FROM Session;`
3. Rename the Session table .
4. Rename the replacement table to Session.
5. If happy Drop the renamed Session table.

Alternately (I think) you could use an AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER to change the NULL to 0 (false).

Either option would have to be done outside of Room or before the RoomDatabase has been built.

Comment: Using a `Boolean` instead of `boolean` helped solve the problem. In the Dao, I'll have to filter by `archived = 0 or archived = NULL` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Referred to [this](https://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2018/11/24/room-database-kotlin-nullable-column/). If you use Kotlin for coding, for making field of models null-able don't use @Nullable instead make field nullable by using "?".
following fields are not nullable.

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "books")
data class Book(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val info: String,
    val type: Int,
    val url: String
)
```

but following field are nullable:

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "books")
data class Book(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val title: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val info: String?,
    val type: Int,
    val url: String?
)
```